# rviz error: "Discarding message from [/move_base] due to empty frame_id"

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, eband-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yesterday, I could navigate my turtlebot with eband_local_planner. but today, I can't move it. So, rviz says following warning.

```
[ WARN] [1401378967.283247030]: MessageFilter [target=map ]: Discarding message from [/move_base] due to empty frame_id.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1401378967.283417501]: Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty
[ WARN] [1401378998.796621804]: Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty
[ WARN] [1401379032.819038628]: Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty
```

Does anyone have any idea to solve these warning?

After that, Eband_local_planner says that it can't make path as following

```
[ INFO] [1401378966.134403366]: Global plan set to elastic band for optimization
[ERROR] [1401378967.110080798]: NO PATH!
[ERROR] [1401378967.110401250]: Failed to get a plan from potential when a legal potential was found. This shouldn't happen.
[ERROR] [1401378998.546064278]: NO PATH!
[ERROR] [1401378998.614580138]: Failed to get a plan from potential when a legal potential was found. This shouldn't happen.
[ WARN] [1401378998.734102440]: Clearing costmap to unstuck robot.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171761/rviz-error:-%22discarding-message-from-%5B/move_base%5D-due-to-empty-frame_id%22/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-05-29**:
My turtlebot moves with base_local_planner, even though same error and warning happens.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-13**:
Can you use ros console to figure out which module these messages originate from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently eband_local_planner is having trouble finding a plan, but is still publishing messages to /move_base. The problem is that these messages have an empty frame_id, as the warning states, so rviz can't make any sense of it. I have never used that planner, so I can't help you solve your problem, but that's all rviz is saying as far as I am aware.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0